# Syntax error: "(" unexpected при запуске приложения AppImage

Tags: linux, qt

Подскажите, пожалуста, как исправить ошибку:
`Syntax error: "(" unexpected`,
возникающая при запуске приложения с расширением .AppImage в ОС Kali Linux для RaspberryPi 4 (ОС взята с оф. сата https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/), установленная на RaspberryPi 4.
Запускаемое приложение было разработано в среде разработки Qt, собрано с помощью утилиты **linuxdeployqt-continuous-x86_64.AppImage** взято с https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt.
На других ОС, установленные виртуально на ПК или на хотсе, приложение запускается нормально и работает, проблема только в ОС, которая установлена на RaspberryPi 4.
Спасибо!

Comment: а Вас не смущает, что утилита имеет в названии x86-64, а малинка как бы arm?

Comment: хм, ну наверно в этом есть какая-то мысль. Я добавил 
`dpkg --add-architecture amd64` это не помогает.
а ещё:
`root@kali:~# uname -a
Linux kali 4.19.118-Re4son-v7l+ #1 SMP Wed May 6 16:33:16 AEST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: x86-64 это и есть amd64. А Вам нужен arm

Comment: @KoVadim, т.е. получается архитектуру ни как не изменить? Я так понимаю, что командой `dpkg --add-architecture amd64` я всего лишь указываю что можно устанавливать пакеты у которых архитектура `amd64`, но это не значит что они будут работать, так как ядро `arm`

Comment: я никогда не пользовался этой тулой, но подозреваю, что у нее должны быть ключики для этого. А Ваш бинарник нужно будет собрать правильным toolchain. Иначе работать не будет.

Comment: @KoVadim, я Вас понял. Спасибо. На этом можно заканчивать.